# Create array from dynamically created input field id's

Tags: php, arrays

What I need to do is retreive all the values of the input fields and store them in the database after pressing a submit button.

Here is what I'm doing:

I retrieve an unknown number of rows from the query, I created an `ID` dynamically  for every input field that can be filled. (so if I get 5 rows, I have 10 input fields, if I get 10 rows, 20 input fields)

This piece:

```
    <input class="goals" type="number" id="'.$row[SCHE_WED].'_'.$row[SCHE_LAND_ID1].'" value="" maxlength="3" '.$active.'/>
```

How do I get all the `id="'.$row[SCHE_WED].'_'.$row[SCHE_LAND_ID1].'"'`s into an array?
I already tried input `name=""`.
(but when using an array, `while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)` ) it doesn't like `name=""` so I changed that to id="")

What I used in another form with the name="" for an input field is this:

```
    $fields = array('','','','',''); // Add all your field names to an array
    $data = array();
    foreach ($fields as $field)
    {
     if (isset($_POST[$field]))
     {
      $data[$field] = $_POST[$field];
      ${$field} = $_POST[$field];
 }
    }
```

But I don't know how or can find how to put the dynamically generated id's in something similar for my code (see below).

```
if (sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt))
{
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) )
    {
    $dateconvert = $row[SCHE_DATE];
    $converted = date("d-m-yy", strtotime($dateconvert));
    echo    '
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:center"; colspan="15">Wedstrijd en plaats gegevens voor wedstrijd '.$row[SCHE_WED].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>   
    <td>Stad: '.$row[Stdn_stad].'</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Inwoners Stad: '.$row[STDN_INWNR_CAP].'</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Stadion naam: '.$row[STDN_NAAM].'</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Capaciteit Stadion: '.$row[STDN_CAP].'</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Datum: '.$converted.'</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Tijd: '.$row[SCHE_TIME].'</td>
    <td></td>
    <td style="text-align:right";>Thuis: '.$row[SCHE_LAND1].'</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>Uit: '.$row[SCHE_LAND2].'</td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input class="goals" type="number" id="'.$row[SCHE_WED].'_'.$row[SCHE_LAND_ID1].'" value="" maxlength="3" '.$active.'/></td>        
    <td> - </td>
    <td><input class="goals" type="number" id="'.$row[SCHE_WED].'_'.$row[SCHE_LAND_ID1].'" value="" maxlength="3" '.$active.'/></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Totokruisje: <input class="goals" type="number" id="toto_'.$row[SCHE_WED].'" value="" maxlength="3" '.$active.'/></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
  ';

    }
}           
  echo '
<tr>
    <td colspan="15"></td>
</tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  ';
  ?>
```

Comment: What are the differences between one goal and the next? Will you be connecting different parent IDs to different goals? Or do you have a single parent ID for all the goals in the form?

Comment: the goals fields are input fields for users to predict outcome on soccer games. so goals = a prediction on soccer game outcome. the .$row[SCHE_WED].'_'.$row[SCHE_LAND_ID1]. creates an unique id for SCHE_WED = game number and the SCHE_LAND_ID1 is for the first team and the SCHE_LAND_ID2 is for the second team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is you can create two input arrays for the goal+team combo.

You could repeat this combo for as many goals as you need.

```
<input type="text" name="teams[]" value="" />
<input type="number" name="goals[]" value="" />
```

Then when your form submits, you have two arrays: `$_POST['teams']` and `$_POST['goals']`. You can use the index to match teams to goals like:

```
foreach($_POST['teams'] as $key => $team) {
   echo $team;
   $goal = $_POST['goals'][$key];
   echo $goal;
}
```

And process as needed. You can add the form elements dynamically with jQuery like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6G7yB/6/

Hope this helps

Edit:

You can also do something like this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php#87650

Comment: can you give me an example how to build the for each array with 3 variables? like, teams,goals and for instance, place?
foreach($_POST['teams'] as $key => $team) {
    $goal = $_POST['goals'][$key];
And thanks :) your solution helped me a great deal, it works for what i'm trying to do :) 
$place = $_post['place'][and then goals and teams];}?
So I can use that combination to store in an insert query...
 
}

Comment: Never mind my question, I found the solution how to combine the foreach as $key answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177958/foreach-with-multiple-variables-in-same-indexes-combined-with-js